# Display values which are in the largest group

Tags: mysql

```
select * from employee where salary In (select MAX(salary) from employee where salary NOT IN (Select MAX(salary) from employee))
```

I have a table "employee" with two columns "name" and "salary" and data like:

```
name    salary

A       10000
B       12000
C       13000
D       12000
E       12000 
F       15000
```

Now when I run this query it shows me:

```
(C 13000)
```

which is wrong output. I want this output:

```
name    salary

B       12000
D       12000
E       12000
```

So, how can I do this?

Comment: How is 12000 > 15000 or 13000.   ??

Comment: I think u wat the largest salary group, i..e Salary paid to most people.

Comment: yes @RehanAzher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE salary = (SELECT distinct salary FROM employee group by salary order by count(salary) desc limit 1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62dd199/2

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the salary with the most people on it then it would be using `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Salary = (
   SELECT
      Salary
   FROM EMPLOYEE
   GROUP BY Salary
   ORDER BY COUNT(Salary) DESC
   LIMIT 1
)
```

I have made an SQL Fiddle as well: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08b183/11/0